# Java - Resetting a value of a element in a list

Tags: java

So I have this list of films sorted in a JList. How these elements are created is sorted in another class. Here's the code for the list.
            filmlist = new FilmList();

```
    //Pre loaded film data
    filmlist.addFilm("The Matrix", "A", "18", "2", 100);
    filmlist.addFilm("Wreck It Ralph", "B", "U", "5", 150);
    filmlist.addFilm("Sin City", "C", "18", "3", 100);
    filmlist.addFilm("Starwars", "D", "PG", "3", 150);
    filmlist.addFilm("Back to the Future", "E", "PG", "2", 80);
    filmlist.addFilm("Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory", "F", "U", "1", 75);
    filmlist.addFilm("Avatar", "G", "PG", "2", 80);
    filmlist.addFilm("Disturba", "H", "PG", "1", 80);
    filmlist.addFilm("Monsters Inc", "I", "U", "1", 100);
    filmlist.addFilm("The Godfather", "J", "18", "1", 100 );

    theFilmList.setModel(filmlist);
```

And I have a method that simulates the purchasing of a ticket for one of these films. Atm it basically prints out the values.

```
    public void buyTicket() {
    String newFilmName = filmNameTF.getText();
    String newLecture = lectureTF.getText();
    String newAge = ageTF.getText();
    String newPrice = priceTF.getText();
    int newSeats = Integer.parseInt(seatsTF.getText()); // convert the int to a String
    int newSeatsNo; // the new number of seats for the film

    newSeatsNo = newSeats - 1;


    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to buy a ticket for " + newFilmName + " at the cost of £" + newPrice,
            "Purchase Ticket", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) 
            == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {// Are you sure dialog      

        if (newFilmName.equals("") || newLecture.equals("") || 
                newAge.equals("") || newPrice.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select a film from the list");
        } else {
            System.out.println("- Receipt -");
            System.out.println("Film: " + newFilmName);
            System.out.println("Lecture Hall: " + newLecture);
            System.out.println("Age Rating: " + newAge);
            System.out.println("Price of Ticket: " + "£" + newPrice);

        }
```

What I wanna do is change the value of the last element in the list which is the number of seats. I can do equations by doing "newSeatsNo = newSeats - 1;". How do I get the value of that equation replaced in the JList?

I hope you understand what I mean, just say if you need more code from any of the classes.

```
public class FilmList extends DefaultListModel {
public FilmList(){
    super();
}

public void addFilm(String film, String  lecture, String age, String price, int seats){
    super.addElement(new FilmSystem(film, lecture, age, price, seats));
}

}
```

Film List class.

Comment: in which class is buyTicket defined? Do you have a Film class? so i can call it like film.buyTicket() and then your filmList is a JList of Film?

Comment: which part of these is the no. of seats? "The Godfather", "J", "18", "1", 100. Also it looks like you used Generics and customized the type of element that can be added filmlist. Can you show the actual declaration/initiation of filmlist?

Comment: Both these pieces of code are in the same class which is my GUI class. The last elements are the no of seats, so in the Godfather it would be 100. I'll edit the question and put the filmlist class in.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use set which is one of the methods under DefaultListModel

```
int lastElem = filmlist.getSize();

filmlist.set( lastElem, new FilmList().addFilm("The Godfather", "J", "18", "1", <new value here>);
```

I haven't tried this code yet as I don't have access to a compiler. But you can find DefaultListModel's available methods here: [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)

Comment: The thing is I want to change the value of the number of films of the film the user picks. So it depends which element they have selected. I haven't tried that code neither but it looks like it's on the lines of what I need to do.